# Angular 5 list only certain value of objects

Tags: angular, ngfor

Let's say I have a list of bank objects

```
this.Banks.detail[0].name
```

Where `[0]` is the index of the banks.
I want to show the list of bank name with ngFor, this is my code:

```
<option *ngFor = "let bank of banks" [value]="combo"> {{Banks.detail.name}}
</option>
```

Which obviously doesn't work.
What is the correct way to list the bank names?

Comment: Could you provide your JSON?

Comment: make slight changes: `<option *ngFor = "let bank of Banks" [value]="combo"> {{bank.detail.name}}
</option>`

Comment: @SangwinGawande (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, name: "BCA", account_name: "Bank BCA", account_number: "", branch: "", …}
1
:
{id: 2, name: "MANDIRI", account_name: "Bank MANDIRI", account_number: "", branch: "", …}
2
:
{id: 3, name: "BRI", account_name: "Bank BRI", account_number: "", branch: "", …}

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig that works, thanks. You should've replied as answer so I can upvote.

Comment: your welcome. i will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make slight changes:

```
<option *ngFor = "let bank of Banks" [value]="combo">
{{bank.detail.name}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
<option *ngFor = "let bank of Banks.detail" [value]="combo"> 
     {{bank.name}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<option *ngFor = "let bank of banks" [value]="combo"> {{bank.detail.name}}
</option>
```